Updating Relationship Fields in Workflows
Can we update a lookup relationship field in a workflow, or can only the master-detail field be updated?

Do you mean updating the lookup itself, or updating a field on the related record?

Remember that Salesforce will stop supporting Workflow Rules in 2025.  As mentioned in the answer, you should start using Flows instead.

Both can be updated from what I recall, but workflow field update actions are limited to using a single, pre-defined value to update a relationship field to so that's not very useful in most cases.
Flows (the successor to Workflows and Process Builder) appear to be more flexible in what they allow you to assign to a relationship field.
